# Extract k bits from any side of hex notation

Tags: c, hex, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
    int X = 0x1234ABCD;
    int Y = 0xcdba4321;
    
    // a) print the lower 10 bits of X in hex notation
    int output1 = X & 0xFF;
    printf("%X\n", output1);

    // b) print the upper 12 bits of Y in hex notation
    int output2 = Y >> 20;
    printf("%X\n", output2);
```

I want to print the lower 10 bits of X in hex notation; since each character in hex is 4 bits, FF = 8 bits, would it be right to & with 0x2FF to get the lower 10 bits in hex notation.

Also, would shifting right by 20 drop all 20 bits at the end, and keep the upper 12 bits only?

Comment: The expression `X & 0xFF` will get only the low *eight* bits. Ten bits would be `0x3ff`.

Comment: Any yes, `Y >> 20` will "drop" the low 20 bits, moving the 12 top bits to the lowest part, and insert zeros at the top.

Comment: Use `unsigned` variables when using hexadecimal. You'll have fewer problems...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's not true!! It will drop the low 20 bits, but will shift in either zeros or ones, depending on the value of the highest bit. For it to always shift in zeros, Y would need to be an unsigned integer!

Comment: PS: If you want to see 2 (or 3) hex digits, the printf format string should specify the width AND specify prepending leading '0's if necessary. Eg "%02X" or "%03X"... Otherwise you may wonder why left-end 0 bits are not showing up in your output.

Comment: To make a mask for N lower bits you can use `(1<<N)-1`

Comment: @dimich Mask better with `unsigned` constants and math: `((1u<<N)-1)`.

Comment: @robthebloke Yeah that's right. Missed that the OP was using signed integers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Y >> 20` is implementation-defined. Since `Y` was set to a number larger than INT_MAX, there will be an implementation-defined conversion with `Y`ending up negative. Then the right shift will either shift in ones or zeroes, depending on implementation (arithmetic vs logical shift).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print the lower 10 bits of X in hex notation; since each character in hex is 4 bits, FF = 8 bits, would it be right to & with 0x2FF to get the lower 10 bits in hex notation.

No, that would be incorrect. You'd want to use 0x3FF to get the low 10 bits. (0x2FF in binary is: 1011111111). If you're a little uncertain with hex values, an easier way to do that these days is via binary constants instead, e.g.

```cpp
    // mask lowest ten bits in hex
    int output1 = X & 0x3FF;
    
    // mask lowest ten bits in binary
    int output1 = X & 0b1111111111;
```

> Also, would shifting right by 20 drop all 20 bits at the end, and keep the upper 12 bits only?

In the case of **LEFT** shift, zeros will be shifted in from the right, and the higher bits will be dropped.

In the case of **RIGHT** shift, it depends on the sign of the data type you are shifting.

```cpp
// unsigned right shift
unsigned U = 0x80000000;
U = U >> 20;
printf("%x\n", U); // prints:  800

// signed right shift
int S = 0x80000000;
S = S >> 20;
printf("%x\n", S); // prints:  fffff800
```

Signed right-shift typically shifts the highest bit in from the left. Unsigned right-shift always shifts in zero.

As an aside: IIRC the C standard is a little vague wrt to signed integer shifts. I believe it is theoretically possible to have a hardware platform that shifts in zeros for signed right shift (i.e. micro-controllers). Most of your typical platforms (Intel/Arm) will shift in the highest bit though.

Comment: C standard --> "An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right."

Comment: Note that `0b1111111111` is not specified in standard C ...  [yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features).

Comment: "If you're a little uncertain with hex values" Then practice. One of the best things my uni did back in the days was to force the students to learn binary and hex _before writing a single line of code_. That way you don't end up writing bad code because you are uncertain. Typing out 32 bits in binary is simply madness and the very reason why the binary notation never made it into the C language (yet).

Answer (score 0):

> print the upper 12 bits of Y in hex notation

- To handle this when the width of `int` is not known, first determine the width with code like `sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT`.  (C specifies it must be at least 16-bit.)
- Best to use `unsigned` or mask the shifted result with an `unsigned`.

```
#include <limits.h>

int output2 = Y;
printf("%X\n", (unsigned) output2 >> (sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT - 12));
// or
printf("%X\n", (output2 >> (sizeof output2 * CHAR_BIT - 12)) & 0x3FFu);
```

- Rare non-2's complement encoded `int` needs additional code - not shown.
- Very rare padded `int` needs other bit width detection - not shown.

Comment: Strictly speaking `%X` wants an unsigned int too. The OP should just drop the signed types.

Comment: @Lundin Agree `%X` wants an `unsigned`.  Both `printf()` already  use `unsigned` types.  Typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 32 bit `int`, then you have the following problems:

- `0xcdba4321` is too large to fit inside an `int`. The hex constant itself will actually be `unsigned int` in this specific case, because of an oddball type rule in C. From there you force an implicit conversion to `int`, likely ending up with a negative number.
- `Y >> 20` right shifts a negative number, which is non-portable behavior. It can either shift in ones (arithmetic shift) or zeroes (logical shift), depending on compiler. Whereas right shifting unsigned types is well-defined and always results in logical shift.
- `& 0xFF` masks out 8 bits, not 10.
- `%X` expects an `unsigned int`, not an `int`.

The root of all your problems is "sloppy typing" - that is, writing `int` all over the place when you actually need a more suitable type. You should start using the portable types from `stdint.h` instead, in this case `uint32_t`. Also make a habit of always ending you hex constants with a `u` or `U` suffix.

A fixed program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t X = 0x1234ABCDu;
    uint32_t Y = 0xcdba4321u;
    printf("%X\n", X & 0x3FFu);
    printf("%X\n", Y >> (32-12));
}
```

The `0x3FFu` mask can also be written as `( (1u<<10) - 1)`.

(Strictly speaking you need to printf the stdint.h types using specifiers from inttypes.h but lets not confuse the answer by introducing those at the same time.)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of high-value answers to this question.

Here's more info that might spark curiosity...

```
int main() {
    uint32_t X;

    X = 0x1234ABCDu; // your first hex number
    printf( "%X\n", X );

    X &= ((1u<<12)-1)<<20; // mask 12 bits, shifting mask left
    printf( "%X\n", X );

    X = 0x1234ABCDu; // your first hex number
    X &= ~0u^(~0u>>12);
    printf( "%X\n", X );

    X = 0x0234ABCDu; // Note leading 0 printed in two styles
    printf( "%X %08X\n", X, X );

    return 0;
}
```

```
1234ABCD
12300000
12300000
234ABCD 0234ABCD
```